# how to train model to identify patterns for predicting only one label '1' in binary classification. while any other pattern will be predicted as '0'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Can i make my LSTM RNN model focus on predicting '1' while it dose not cares to predict '0'.
To make my question more clear. i am trying to make LSTM binary classification where i want to predict buy signals. model can only focus of what pattern is essential to predict 1. and it neglects patterns that predict '0'/don't buy.
According to my understanding model tries to get both 1's and 0's right. but i don't want it to care about what sequence gives output '0'.
Hopefully i am making sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The patterns of both 0 and 1 are intertwined, to say, you will optimize for one is not right because if you are trying to optimize for 1, you are inadvertently also, optimizing for 0. What you can do is make your model better:

1. Trying changing the number of layers and the number of units in your layer.
2. Consider using dropout.
3. Increase your dataset size, if possible.
4. Change your loss function. (In this you can incorporate your idea of penalizing your model for 0 predictions)

Answer (score 0):

You can encourage your model to pay more attention the examples of a certain class by using sample weighting, by resampling your data, or with a custom loss function.

In a multi-class scenario this sounds like you are looking for one-vs-all concept

However in a binary prediction you cannot completely ignore the other direction otherwise you will be left with only one meaningful choice and your neural network will simply always predict it.

As an example imagine if some said they would pay you $1000 dollars every day that you correctly predicted the stock market would go up, but you get no money for correctly predicting when the market will go down. What would you do? Just predict 'up' every single day because you would maximize your chance of getting money since there is no advantage to ever predict 'down'.